# facing error while install imagemagick Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagemagick

I am new to use ubuntu, to install imagemagick I have run below command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but it showing error

[image]

I have executed below commands as well but not able to install

```
sudo -i
cd
apt-get install build-essential checkinstall && apt-get build-dep imagemagick -y
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.8.7-7.tar.gz
tar xzvf ImageMagick-6.8.9-1.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-6.8.9-1/
./configure --prefix=/opt/imagemagick-6.8 && make
checkinstall
https://gist.github.com/rodleviton/74e22e952bd6e7e5bee1
```

Answer (score 1):

Google has dropped the support for 32-bit version for chrome on Linux and that is the reason you are seeing that error.

1. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` - You would need `sudo`
2. Replace the existing line with `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`
3. Run `sudo apt-get update` now.

And what is the error you are seeing when you are trying to install `imagemagick`?

Comment: Above line is already there but it showing same errors. Below is my file code "### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"

Comment: `[arch=amd64]` is missing in your file.
So replace `deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main` with `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`.

Comment: Okay that I have added now I am looking whats get change due to it

Comment: that run successfully with o/p Reading package lists... Done                                                  
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551

Comment: Run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551` to fix that, public key issue. 

What is the error you are seeing while installing imagemagick?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111118/discussion-between-anand-jain-and-ravitezu).